# There's no 'range' parameter in series.plot.hist, but how this work?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

There's no range argument in [pandas.Series.plot.hist](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.plot.hist.html) or [pandas.Series.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html#pandas.Series.plot).
But the code below works. How does it work?

```
#wnba is Dataframe, so wnba['PTS'] is series.
wnba['PTS'].plot.hist(range = (1,600), bins = 3)
```

Comment: [`**kwds`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs)

Comment: @Adelin That's why I also linked Series.plot. There's no range in Series.plot, too.

Comment: The documentation states `**kwds : keywords, Options to pass to matplotlib plotting method`. Meaning, that if this calls `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`, `range` will be passed to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`plot.hist`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.1/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L2817-L2833) takes `**kwds` so, already, however you call it (with whatever keyword args), it'll have a correct syntax.

Semantically:

1. `hist` calls `self` **by passing** `kind='hist'` argument,
2. which means [`self.__call__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.1/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L2726),
3. which, in turn calls [`plot_series`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.1/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1981) that establishes the `ax` layer through the `_get_ax_layer` method,
4. then [`_plot`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.1/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L593) is called with this `ax` **and** with the `kind='hist'` argument
5. which, eventually, means that the [HistPlot](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.1/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1310) class will be used
6. that finally extracts the `range` kwarg via [range=self.kwds.get('range', None)](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.1/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1328)

It's all a matter of patiently following the breadcrumbs.